# How to wire switched light fixture in place of ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I removed a ceiling fan that had four wires.  I have installed a normal ceiling light that remains on regardless of the position of the switch.  The switch worked with the ceiling fan light. How can I figure out the right wiring to use the switch for the light?

Comment: How was it wired before, and how did you rewire it? Did you identify which wires were hot, switched, neutral, and ground before disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

*Typically* there are two hot wires coming into a fan box that has separate switches for the fan and light kit. *Typically* the black is used for the fan, and the red is for the light kit. That said, other color combinations are possible.

*Typically*, the blue wire from your fan/light combo supplies the light kit. Whichever of the two hot wires was connected to the blue fan/light wire is your huckleberry.

If you want more help, post more information.